# How the initialization of Laravel facades works (on 'DB' example)?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is the `DB` (`DataBase`) facade example:

```php
$results = DB::select('select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1]);
```

The static method `select` delegates the transaction to appropriate Data Base Management System
depended on environment configuration:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
```

Here, could be MySQL, PosgreSQL or other systems (not sure about notations) instead of `sqlite`.

But how it works? How the `DB` facade has been initialized and how `DB::select` will behave if `DB` has not been initialized?

### My guesses

The simplest but not acceptable from the viewpoint of source code quality implementation is:

```php
class DB {

  public static function select(query, arguments) {
    switch ENV.DB_CONNECTION {
        case "sqlite":
          SQLite::select(query, arguments);
          break;
        case "mysql"
          SQLite::select(query, arguments);
          break;
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

But there was not some kind of initialization there. Below implementation has `initialize` method, and if don't call it before usage of other methods,
the exception will be thrown:

```php
class DB {

  private static $Executor;

  public static function initialize(ENV) {
    switch ENV.DB_CONNECTION {
        case "sqlite":
          self::$Executor = SQLite;
          break;
        case "mysql"
          self::$Executor = MySQL;
          break;
      // ...
    }   
    
  }


  public static function select(query, arguments) {

   if (is_null(self::$Executor)) {
     throw new Exception("The DB facade has not been initilized.", 1);
   }

    DB::Executor.select(query, arguments);
  }

  public static function delete(query) {

    if (is_null(self::$Executor)) {
      throw new Exception("The DB facade has not been initilized.", 1);
    }

    DB::Executor.delete(query);
  }
}
```

But I'm sure that the Laravel development team has wrote something much better than above code.

Comment: That is not exactly how it works, it's a bit more complicated that that. Facades are in fact the static ways of accessing the service providers. You should learn and understand the architectural concepts of Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/lifecycle

Comment: The thread is this: 1) Laravel framework starts 2) It registers the service providers within the service container 3) It "boots" the service providers

Comment: Facades are the way to access the registered providers

Comment: "Service providers" are in fact (and I think this is the concept that confuses everyone) classes that you write by hand, but you instruct Laravel to instantiate them automatically via Service Container, so that when you need them in your controllers/routes/views you won't have to instantiate them yourself

Comment: That's the point of this whole "Service Container/Provider" mechanism :)